# Lucene as a lookup table for fuzzy string matching

Tags: lucene, lookup

I have some files with contents like that:

```
PERSON (filename)
Keanu Reeves
Carrie-Anne Moss
Laurence Fishburne
Hugo Weaving
```

I want to give a person's name and get as result the filename (PERSON). I have used OpenNPL DictionaryNameFinder and I can get it. But, in my scenario rarely the lookup phrase matches the exact name. So, I want to be able to do a *fuzzy string matching*, for example, giving `Carrie Anne Moss` or `Reeves Keanu` and get PERSON.

Can I use Lucene to achieve this task? If yes, which class(es) should I study?

Comment: why you could do that with basic HashMap? What's the purpose of using Lucene?

Comment: I want to do matches with fuzzy strings. `Carrie Anne Moss` is not an exact match with the contents of the file.

Comment: so, please update your question with this requirement, i will try to answer it